# Discuss the solutions to $x^2 - |x| = mx(x + 1)$ depending on $m \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Consider the equation:

$$x^2 - |x| = mx(x + 1)$$

with $m \in \mathbb{R}$. I have to find the solutions of this equation depending on $m$.

This is what I tried:

$$x^2 - |x| = mx(x + 1)$$

$$x^2 - |x| -mx^2 -mx = 0$$

$$mx^2 + mx -x^2 + |x| = 0$$

Case $1$: $x < 0 \Rightarrow |x| = -x$,

$$mx^2 + mx -x^2 -x = 0$$

$$(m - 1)x^2 + (m - 1 )x = 0$$

$$(m - 1)(x^2 + x) = 0$$

So we have either:

$$m - 1= 0 \Rightarrow m = 1$$

Or:

$$x^2 + x = 0$$

We get:

$$x_1 = 1 \hspace{2cm} x_2 = - 1$$

But since we're working with the case when $x < 0$ we only get one solution:

$$x = -1$$

Case $2$: $x \ge 0 \Rightarrow |x| = x$,

$$mx^2 + mx -x ^2 + x = 0$$

$$x^2(m - 1) + (m + 1)x = 0$$

$$x[x(m - 1) + m + 1] = 0$$

We have either:

$$x = 0$$

Or:

$$x(m - 1) + m + 1 = 0$$

$$x = - \dfrac{m + 1}{m - 1}$$

So I concluded that:

For $m = 1$ the solutions are:

$$x \in (-\infty, 0]$$

And for $m \ne 1$ the solutions are:

$$x_1 = 0 \hspace{2cm} x_2 = -1 \hspace{2cm} x_3 = - \dfrac{m + 1}{m - 1}$$

Is this correct? Should I have solved this differently? More efficiently? What could be improved/corrected to my solution?

Comment: In the cas $x\geq 0$, you don't make sure that the solution $x=-\frac{m+1}{m-1}$ is greater than or equal to 0. it's not always the case. Otherwise, the discussion must be done according to the values of the parameter m.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette So you're saying that I need to make sure that $- \dfrac{m + 1}{m - 1}$ is greater than or equal to $0$? Is that it? And what about the rest? Does that look right?

Comment: For x, study the sign of $-\frac{m+1}{m-1}$ or more simply the sign of $-(m+1)(m-1)$. For the rest $x^2+x=x(x+1)=0$ has 0 and -1 as solutions. So in the case 1, $x_1$ is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Case 1, your result is correct but you need to change $x_1=1$ to $x_1=0$. Also you need to state the other solution that you found i.e. if $m=1$ then all $x<0$ are solutions.

For Case 2 when $x\ne 0$, $x = - \dfrac{m + 1}{m - 1}$ requires $(1+m)(1-m)$ to be positive i.e $|m|<1$. So the solutions you have obtained should be stated as
$$x=-1,x=0, x=- \dfrac{m + 1}{m - 1}  \text { if } |m|<1.$$

Your method of solution was fine so perhaps the main thing is to check your final answer with the original equation (e.g checking what happens if $m=1$) and being careful to state your results more precisely.